# When scrolling over the div (if visible), start jQuery script on this div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, progress-bar

I need solution to my problem with animate than you scrollin over the div. If I set this code out of this function, I mean this part of code

```
$('#bar'+dataNr).find('span').removeClass().addClass(dataColor).animate({width: dataWidth});
```

Everything is working as well, all events like mouseenter, movemose etc. When I try to animate this progress bar when page is scrolling this isn't working. Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/y2th0cwk/

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var dataColor = $(this).data('color');
  var dataWidth = $(this).data('width');
  var dataNr = $(this).data('nr');

  if($(this).scrollTop()>0){
  $('#bar'+dataNr).find('span').removeClass().fadeIn(1000).addClass(dataColor).animate({width: dataWidth});
 }else{
   $('#bar'+dataNr).find('span').removeClass(dataColor);
  }
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;

    border-radius: 5px;
  }

.progress-bar span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #34c2e3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container skillsBar">
      <h2>Skills</h2>
      <div class="skills1">
        <p class="changeBar" data-width="30%" data-color="blue" data-nr="1">PHP/WordPress</p>
          <div id="bar1" class="progress-bar">
            <span></span>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why my datas in wrong? I need to get datas from HTML to set progress bar when scrolling over this div. When I put `$('#bar'+dataNr).find('span').removeClass().fadeIn(1000).addClass(dataColor).animate({width: dataWidth});` progress bar is working. In my case want to active progress bar when you will scroll over div with progres bars.

https://jsfiddle.net/k5gc96ex/

Comment: check my edit - answer is there. (Or provide the full source code - html as well. Now its hard to figure out what is where).